# JS Performance: Event Handler inside Condition vs Condition inside Event Hander

Tags: javascript, performance, conditional-statements, dom-events

I'm relatively new to JS but I'm very aware that performance is a very important issue in web development, hence this question:

I have searched and found some relevant threads (such as: [Javascript pattern: Conditional event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471607/javascript-pattern-conditional-event-handler)), but I have found this confusing as my scenario is far simpler and doesn't involve any advanced concepts such as classes.

For example context, imagine my website contains pages of various 'types' as defined by differing body class="type" tags. For clarity, we could have body class="member-details", body class="club-details" and body class="random-page-type". Imagine there were quite a few, say 20 possible body class types.

Consider the situation wherein I may wish to bind a particular click event handler to an element if the body is of some certain types and another if it's others.

**The question is:**

Is it better performance-wise to place handler in condition or condition in handler? For clarity, pseudocode:

**1) condition inside event handler**

```
ON DOCUMENT READY {
    if page type is 'club-details' || page type is 'x' || page type is 'y' {
        bind function1 ();
    }
}
```

**2) event handler inside condition**

```
if page type is 'club-details' || page type is 'x' || page type is 'y' {
    ON DOCUMENT READY {
        bind fuction1();
    }
}
```

This is a very simplified example, but I guess I'm asking for info regarding performance of always binding an event as in example 1 or decided whether to bind through an iterative condition as in example 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Javascript Events are executed asynchronously, your example is not the term of performance but memory. The second example will take less memory than the first one just because less events are bound. Client side performance is not that important in comparison with the server side one. That being said, you should consider writing nice and readable code over trivial performance benefits. Javascript is really fast nowaday.

Comment: thanks for your response, which is quite informative. I'm new to the etiquette here but before I mark this as an accepted answer I'll wait and see if anybody else chimes in :)